# Incomplete RewriteRules in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've following rules in `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^captcha/(.*)$ captcha/captcha.php?cid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.(html|php)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|(css|images|js|captcha)/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1 [QSA]
```

It should do the internal the following (without changing users URL in browser)

```
/something => /index.php?get=something
/?abc=def => /index.php?abc=def
/something?some=var => /index.php?get=something&some=var
```

technically it does most things I want. But it should do the rewrite without changing users URL in browser (it should only redirect internal). But for first and third example the users browser is redirected as follows

```
/something => /something/?get=something
/something?some=var => /something/?get=something&some=var
```

But that's not what I want (the URL should not be manipulated - it has to be an internal rewrite). Anyone there who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the infamous trailing slash problem.

Actually your above `.htaccess` will work fine if an URL is accessed with a trailing slash at the end. i.e. `yourdomain/something/` but it will not work for `yourdomain/something`

#### Why?

With out a trailing slash apache will treat it as a file and look for it. Failing to find it. It will try to fix itself by adding a trailing slash at the end.

By this time, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|rob...` would have already been satisfied and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1 [QSA]` would have already been proccessed once. and the URL would already have `?get=something`.

Now , after Apache adds the trailing slash, and processes the `.htaccess` its not an internal redirect(`200`). so

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

will fail. And `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|rob...` will satisfy and the  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1 [QSA]` will get processed again.

And also apache will set the URL for a temporary redirect soon after adding a trailing slash.
At this point your URL looks like `yourdomian.com/something/?get=something`.This is why the URI gets reflected in the browser. i.e.

```
/something => /something/?get=something
/something?some=var => /something/?get=something&some=var
```

but your `index.php` will actually be seeing:

```
/something => ?get=something/&get=something
/something?some=var => ?get=something/&get=something&some=var
```

---

#### The Sol:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php

#add these 2 lines
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#add these
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteRule ^captcha/(.*)$ captcha/captcha.php?cid=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.(html|php)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|(css|images|js|captcha)/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?get=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

- Checks for whether a file exists.

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f [OR]`
- Checks that request URI does not have an extension at the end

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w+$`
- Checks for whether there is a trailing slash at the end.

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$`
- If the above satisfy, redirect the current URL with a trailing slash.

  `RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]`
  `R`(redirect) by default has `302` (Temporary Redirect).

Comment: I've updated my post a bit. Have a look at my examples, how redirects behave now.

Comment: ok, behaviour is better now, but `/something` redirect still to `/something/` (so the `?get=something`disappeared, but the trailing slash still exists). These rules are ported from Nginx. And when I open page in Firefox with Firebug all is fine (access gives code 200), but when accessing this page on second server with Apache, there is a redirect (URL is `something` code 302) and second call to `/something/` with code 200. Would it help, if I post my original Nginx rules?

Comment: Or did I understand you right, that this is an Apache _bug_ that the trailing slash has to be there?

Comment: Hi again, there seems to be another problem, when doing a POST with jQuery's ajaxForm. The POST request seems to be redirected and so my POST data is lost!? Is there a way, where we can exchange by email?